# Why doesn't PHP support curly-brace expansion of consts in a string?

Tags: php, constants, curly-braces

PHP supports this:

```
$z = 5;
$str = "z is $z";  // result: "z is 5"
```

and it supports this:

```
$c = new StdClass();
$c->x = 9;
$str = "x is {$c->x}";  // result: "x is 9"
```

but it does NOT support this:

```
class abc
{
   const n = 2;
}
$str = "x is {abc::n}";  // result: "x is {abc::n}"
```

Why does PHP **not** support insertion of consts via the curly-brace syntax? Seems like it should...

Comment: The PHP tokenizer looks for `$` in double quotes. Variables are the primary interpolation target in strings, not expressions. And `{` is just syntactic sugar around variables, but not actually supposed to start complex interpretation within strings. It's cleverly misused sometimes to do that, but it's really meant for variables only. That's why {constants} aren't supported.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The curly syntax is the extended **variable** syntax. It is used to interpolate *variables* into strings. And as in PHP variables start with `$` everything else will yield a syntax error.

But what you can do is call variable-functions. Thus you could do:

```
$_ = function ($expr) { return $expr; };

echo "Something {$_(Class::Constant)}";
```

But that's a hack which normally isn't appropriate. Instead please use string concatenation:

```
echo 'Something ' . Class::Constant;
```

Comment: really nice! I would consider this on php 5.3

Comment: Better yet: `$_ = "htmlspecialchars";` which works more universally.